# How to understand why Service crashes?

Tags: android, service

It crashes on the actual device after undefined period of time (can be in a few days). The error message shows that it will be stopped and just one OK button. Is there any way to get a log to see what happened? (each time I keep device connected to the PC, I am not able to catch the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). They've got a very good [Wiki post](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRA3HowTo?tm=6) on how to implement it.

It will post an entry to a Google Spreadsheet form with a stacktrace and some other useful information if a crash occurs. Very useful.

Implement it and then just keep an eye on your Google Spreadsheet for crash reports.